# User Defined Table Types Not Available

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Do you need a specific version of Sql Server 2008 to have TVP (Table Value Parameters) or Table Types?

I don't have the folder under types and I get an error when trying to create one:

```
CREATE Type EntityTable AS TABLE
 (EntityId int
 ,EntityName varchar(max)
 ,EntityFriendlyName varchar(max)
 ,IconPath varchar(max)
 ,EntityDescription varchar(max)
 ,EntityToolTip varchar(max)
 ,TableName varchar(max)
 ,EntityrFriendlyNamePlural varchar(max)
 ,AttachNotes bit
 ,AttachDocuments bit
 ,AllowDuplicates bit)
GO
```

error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask a stupid question...

They have Sql Server 2005 installed.

My wrong assumption that they were running 2008.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185